# Who do anyone work with FBReader open source?

Tags: android, ebook-reader

Newly, I want to work with FBReader. I took it's codes from [github](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ) and download [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) and [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). But I have several problems.

I need your help for config and use these codes. I install Cygwin and try to config it but I get the following error in codes:

**1. I get error in main.xml :** *"error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fadeScrollbars' in package 'android' "*

**2. I get errors in src/... :** *" The import org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android.R cannot be resolved  "*  (for line: import org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android.R; )

**3. In HowToBuild file I don't understand which create '*local.properties*' file and how to set address for sdk.dir && ndk.dir**

**4. In .bashrc file where should I insert parameters? (which line)**

**5. Does Android NDK should config? How?**

I search and study a lot of, But I can't use FBReader. Could you help me, please?
By the way, I used Eclipse.

Thanks and Regards, Omid

Comment: have u got solution ? which version of FBReader u are using ?

Answer (score 1):

you may build NDK using cmd.

ndk-build -C your_project_location

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066025/ndk-build-error) link will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did: I downloaded and extracted the NDK.  Then I ran the NDK-build command on the project directory in CMD:

```
cd: <PROJECT SOURCE DIRECTORY>
<PATH-TO-NDK FOLDER>\ndk-build
```

After its built, follow steps inside of the FBBuilder readme. Setting the path are super easy.  Create file local.properties in the root of FBReader project, and inside it enter the SDK and NDK paths just as shown in the readme.  If you have winodws, your path would be something like this C:\android\android_ndk, etc.

Once you do that, you should come across the following error: **org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android.R is unresolved.** This even I don't know how to fix.  I'm currently researching this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same problem. First try to resolve other issues in your project. This file is generated automatically by your sdk, so don't bother about that. Also the package name in your manifest file must be same as below:-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="108021"
    android:versionName="1.8.2" >
```

As soon as other errors will be resolved,sdk will create this file when you refresh project or clean the project.

Comment: user2392492 which version of FBReader you have implemented ?