# NDK- Build error

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am buliding a NDK for fbReader. But I am unable to build NDK. 
whn I am using cmd ndk-build the it says no command found. 
But I fill full path of NDK hen ite show the below error..

```
Android NDK: Application x86-4.2.1 targets unknown ABI 'all'
```

Android NDK: Please fix the APP_ABI definition in /cygdrive/d/fbReader/jni/Application.mk
  Android NDK: to use a set of the following values: armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
  /cygdrive/c/Programs/android-ndk-r4b/build/core/add-application.mk:99: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the ndk location(cd C:\android\ndk) using command prompt.
Then type the command

```
ndk-build -C your_project_location
```

Hope this will get you in the right direction. You can find more information on "ndk-build" using the command

```
ndk-build --help
```

Comment: this error occurred. 
C:\Programs\android-ndk-r4b>#!/bin/sh
'#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I asked you type "ndk-build -C your_project_path". I don't understand the above command (#!/bin/sh)

Comment: I'm using ndk r8. May be this will be an issue with your version. Try again by updating your ndk.

Comment: Its working nw.. bt it show one error on last of compilation.

Comment: Sorry but I get error again 
There is a [link](http://pastebin.com/BS5pjseJ) of Error
Please Help me out..

Comment: i followed your instructions but got Invalid argument stop.  @user2853418

Answer (score 0):

Your project is using older ndk-build which relies on `Android.mk` and `Application.mk`

In

```
Application.mk

APP_PLATFORM := android-14

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a mips x86

#APP_OPTIM := debug

APP_OPTIM := release
```

change APP_ABI to only armeabi-v7a